# Formulation of language and regular expressions

Tags: regex, dfa, formal-languages, automaton

I can't figure out what is the formal language and regular expression
of this automaton :

**DFA automaton**

[image: Screen Shot]

I know that the instance of 'b' or 'a' have to be even.
At first I thought the language was:

**L = {(a^i)(b^j) | i(mod2) = j(mod2) = 0, i,j>=0}**

But the automaton can start from 'b', so the language is incorrect.
also, the regular expression i found, isn't match either ((aa)* + (bb)*)* -

can't get abab for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex I got by progressively ripping out nodes (order: 3,1,2,0) is:

```
(aa|bb|(ab|ba)(bb|aa)*(ab|ba))*
```

As far as I can tell, that's the simplest it goes. (I'd love to know if anyone has a simpler reduction—I'm actually taking a test on this stuff this week!)

#### Step-by-step process

We start off by adding a new start and accept state. Every old accept state (in this case, there's only one) gets linked to the new accept state with an ε transition:

[image: step 1—added new start and end states]

Next, we rip out state 3. We need to preserve all paths that run through state 3. In this case we've added a path from state 0 back to itself, paths from state 0 to state 2, and state 2 back to itself:

[image: step 2—removed state 3]

We do the same with state 1:

[image: step 3—state 1 removed]

We can simplify this a bit: we'll concatenate the looping-back transitions with commas. (At the end, this will turn into the union operator (`|` or `⋃` etc. depending on your notation.)

[image: step 4—simplified]

We'll remove state 2 next, and get everything smooshed onto one big loop:

[image: step 5—state 2 removed]

Loops become stars; we remove the last state so we just have a transition from the start state to the end state connected with one big regular expression:

[image: step 6—all states removed]

And that's our regular expression!

#### Language definition

You're pretty close with the language definition. If you can allow something a little looser, it would be this:

```
L = { w | w contains an even number of 'a's and 'b's }
```

The problem with your definition is that you start the string `w` off with `a` every time, whereas the only restriction is on the parity of the number of `a`'s and `b`'s.

Comment: Wow, that was very helpful ! thanks for the extensive details and good luck with your test :)

Comment: I added some pictures too; hopefully that illuminates the process. I'm glad I got some test practice! :) Thanks for furnishing me with a good practice problem.